# Showing that the following set is measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

1. Let
   $X={1,2,3,\ldots\,n}$ and $A = P(X)$.

Define:
$\mu(a)=\frac{|a|}{n}$ for $a\in{A}$. Prove that $\mu$ is a measure!

My try:
It is obvious that $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.
Let $E_1,E_2,\ldots,\inA$, and suppose $E_i$ are disjoint sets , let $E=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i$.

If each $E_i=\emptyset$ then $E=\emptyset$ and $\mu(E)=0$. And obviously $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_i)=0$.
We can notice that each $E_i$ is a finite set (since $X$ is finite so it's power set is also finite and each $E_i\in{P(X)}$).
Thus, $\mu(E_i)= \frac{|E_i|}{n}$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \mu(E_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{|E_i|}{n}$,.
On the other hand, $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i$ is an union of disjoint finite sets, therefore $\mu (\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i)=\ frac{|\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_i|}{n}= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|E_i|}{n}$ .
So the 2-nd axiom also works.

Is that enough?

Thanks

Comment: These seems like two different questions, which is not allowed here afaik.

Comment: Okay, will edit it

Comment: Is $X = \{1, \dots, n\}$ and $P(X)$ the power set of $X$? Also, when $E_{i_0}\neq \emptyset$ why will $E = E_{i_0}$, there can be other nonempty sets. It might be useful to observe that the power set of a finite set is finite.

Comment: Yes , X and P(X) are what you mentioned.Yes, but how then to do this?

Comment: @stackex33 , i edited my answer, can you take a look on it?

Comment: Yes, it looks right. Basically, the cardinality of a finite disjoint union is (the finite) sum of cardinalities (which are also finite here). Also, there is no need to consider two separate cases when $E_i$ are empty and nonempty.